# Ubuntu - How direct example.com/opencart/index.php to http://example.com/ and www.example.com?

Tags: php, web, ubuntu-16.04, vps, opencart-3

I just created a website on VPS using Ubuntu and installed OpenCart. When i open it appears like this, http://example.com/opencart/index.php. Is there a way to shorten or direct to http://example.com and www.example.com ?

Maybe i missed some setting that i had to do. Please someone help me step by step to solve this problem, and because i just learned to create a website.

Thank you,

I Wayan Arthana

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can set the virtual host blow:

Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "/home/xxx/opencart"  
    ServerName myvirtualhost.com  
    DirectoryIndex index.html  index.php
    <Directory "/home/xxx/opencart">  
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride None  
    Order allow,deny  
    Allow from all  
    </Directory>  
    ErrorLog "logs/myvirtualhost.com-error.log"  
    CustomLog "logs/myvirtualhost.com-access.log" common  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, what should i fill for "/home/xxx/opencart"?, what do you mean like this /var/www/html or other

Comment: what is your server ? if it is apache ,you can edit the file: /usr/loca/apche/etc/httpd.conf

Comment: Apache2 that’s my server

Comment: you should edit the configure file. the path may be is /usr/loca/apche/etc/httpd.conf

Comment: Ok thanks lyq’s, i wanna to trying now. If I find error, can you help me again :)